# Passport Custom Callback Info

Tags: javascript, authentication, passport.js

I'm implementing a custom callback in PassportJS, however the additional info is not being passed through to the callback.

The documentation states:

> An optional info argument will be passed, containing additional
>   details provided by the strategy's verify callback.

Such that if I were to pass the following to the callback:

```
return done(null, false, {message: 'Authentication failed.'});
```

with this demo code...

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('basic', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.status(401).json({message: info.message}); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.status(200).json({message: 'success'});
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The info variable should contain a message field with the above mentioned value, however the info variable only contains the following:

> "Basic realm=\"Users\""

I've looked at countless examples but I cannot figure out why the additional info is not being attached to the info variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to add details . You may have to use flash message (connect-flash) library to send flash message and read them .
See if this fits your requirement

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {},
    function(username, password, done) {
      var promise =authenticateService.authenticateUser(username,password);

      promise.then(function(authToken)
      {
        if(authToken=="INVALID CREDENTIALS")
        {
           return done(null, false,{});
        }else{

          return done(null, {
             username: username,authToken:authToken
           },{"sucess":"sucesss"});
        }
      })
    })
);
```

Comment: Yeah I saw the flash middleware but thought it would be simpler to pass the error message through the info variable. Just can't understand why it's not working when all the documentation suggests it's fairly simple. I am using the basic strategy though. Is it not supported in the basic strategy or something...?